# How can I turn a background visibility on and off with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following CSS:

```
#load-icon
{
    background: url(/Images/loaders/mask-loader.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 99; width: 32px; height: 32px;
    z-index: 99; 
    margin-top: 9px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
    margin-right: 5px; 
    display: none;
}
```

I was using the following code to make it visible and not-visible:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $('#load-icon').show(500);
});
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    $('#load-icon').hide();
});
```

However the background is used for spacing and when it is hidden then the #load-icon uses no space which is not what I want.

How can I make it so that the #load-icon always uses space of 32px and the gif just becomes visible or not visible? If it makes it easier I am not too concerned about fade-in or fade out durations.

Here's a fiddle that shows where it is used: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BcPjz/4/)

Update: I really need a way that does not involve setting the background image to none and then back to the gif. That's because I may well be using different CSS styles and I can't code the gif name into my javascript.

Comment: try ,make a div and set the space 32p and in div use the gif

Comment: I am not sure I follow what you are saying. Can you have a look at the fiddle. I already have a 32px div. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $('#load-icon').fadeTo(0,0.0);
});
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    $('#load-icon').fadeTo(0,1.0);
});
```

Comment: Your answer looks very promising. How should I set my background up initially to not be visible. The solution I currently have that's not working with spacing is: #load-icon { background: url(/Images/loaders/mask-loader.gif);
  display: none;
}

Answer (score 2):

you should set in jquery background none.. i.e

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var loadicon = $('#load-icon').css('background');
    $('#load-icon').css('background','none');

    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        $('#load-icon').css('background',loadicon);
    });
    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        $('#load-icon').css('background','none');
    });
});
```

Comment: I was thinking about this but then when I want to make it visible again I would have to code in my javascript the image name and I may have a different image depending on my color theme with the CSS I am using.

Comment: see my edit, this shows how to save the background attributes, and then re-apply them at a later date by calling the last line - this way it doesn't matter what the attributes are for different stylesheets etc, it'll use whatever the current one is.

Comment: Thanks but there's still a problem because the default state needs to be that it doesn't show :-(  Display: none works great if only it would not make the width of my div go down to nothing. Did you get a chance to check out my fiddle. It's not an exact copy of my code but you'll see what I mean. I need that image there to occupy space but just not show up until an ajax event starts.

Comment: i'm not following you, this is how it should work, what div width is going down to nothing? http://jsfiddle.net/BcPjz/7/

Comment: Your solution works but I am trying to find a solution if possible that will work from an initial state of not being visible. The solution by yckart might be what I need. I am just not sure how to set it up at the start.

Comment: my amendment now makes it non-visible by initial state.